# How do I parse a yaml string with python?

Tags: python, yaml

I see an API and many examples on how to parse a yaml file but what about a string?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: FYI YAML is not safe. It is susceptible to vulnerabilities that allows the user to execute code on your servers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrW-HSHP0ws

Comment: @AlanSTACK thanks for the heads up, I was looking for a quick way to try some things, in particular how multi-line strings are parsed in yaml.

Comment: @KlausD.  this remark would have been more appropriate if there was something obvious to try.  `yaml.load/safe_load` is polymorphic in what it accepts, but if all the examples show files, leaves one to look for something else to handle strings, as json does it with `load`/`loads`.  Hard to try using a function that doesn't exist and there's nothing wrong with ... just asking a question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here is the best way I have seen so far demonstrated with an example:

```
import yaml

dct = yaml.safe_load('''
name: John
age: 30
automobiles:
- brand: Honda
  type: Odyssey
  year: 2018
- brand: Toyota
  type: Sienna
  year: 2015
''')

assert dct['name'] == 'John'
assert dct['age'] == 30
assert len(dct["automobiles"]) == 2
assert dct["automobiles"][0]["brand"] == "Honda"
assert dct["automobiles"][1]["year"] == 2015
```

Comment: When I use this method, the type of `dct` is still string

Comment: you should use `yaml.safe_load` for untrusted inputs

Comment: if you need to install the library, be aware that it is `pip install pyyaml` but `import yaml`

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to wrap the string in StringIO, the `safe_load` method accepts strings:

```py
In [1]: yaml.safe_load("{1: 2}")           
Out[1]: {1: 2}
```