# Python - downloading a yaml file from github using PyGitHub get_contents and trying to convert it to dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, yaml

I have a python script that downloads file_content from repo using repo.get_contents.
so I have used -

```
contents = repo.get_contents(
    './some_file.yaml', ref='master').decoded_content.decode()
```

And now I have the content of the yaml file as a string of -
\nkey1:\n-a\n-b-n-c\nkey2

How can I convert it to dict with keys and values?
Can I pull it to dict using the function? or convert this string somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a duplicated question. [how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-string-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186125/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-string-with-python)

```py
import yaml

dct = yaml.safe_load('''
name: John
age: 30
automobiles:
- brand: Honda
  type: Odyssey
  year: 2018
- brand: Toyota
  type: Sienna
  year: 2015
''')
assert dct['name'] == 'John'
assert dct['age'] == 30
assert len(dct["automobiles"]) == 2
assert dct["automobiles"][0]["brand"] == "Honda"
assert dct["automobiles"][1]["year"] == 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyYAML](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml)

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Run your code as shown bellow :

```
import yaml

yml_file = #your yml file

json_file = yaml.load(yml_file)
```

Comment: I have a yaml file in the repo, not in my directories.
Get_content just downloads the content into a variable. Therefore, I can't do yaml.load..
I have only the string of keys and values separated by "\n"